# Charity Donation WooCommerce Checkout

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

I'm using the code below to add three buttons to the WooCommerce checkout page so customers can leave a donation. It's working as it should be, but it would be great if I can highlight one of the buttons when a customer adds a donation to their cart and disable the other two.

Any thoughts on how I can get this to work?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'charity_checkout_add_on', 9999 );
 
function charity_checkout_add_on() {
   $product_ids = array( 59355 );
   $in_cart = false;
   foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
      $product_in_cart = $cart_item['variation_id'];
      if ( in_array( $product_in_cart, $product_ids ) ) {
         $in_cart = true;
         break;
      }
   }
   if ( ! $in_cart ) {
      echo '<div id="charity-donation">';
      echo '<h6>Heading text</h6>';
      echo '<p>Explanation</p>';
      echo '<a class="charity-button" href="?add-to-cart=59356">€0,50</a><a class="charity-button" href="?add-to-cart=59357">€1,00</a><a class="charity-button last" href="?add-to-cart=59358">€2,50</a>';
      echo '</div>';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding the HTML for the buttons you can loop over the `$product_ids` array to fetch and build up the HTML dynamically. This will work for both simple and variable products. You should always escape these values where possible: see https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/

You could then simply add a css class to the button if the product is in the cart by comparing its ID against any of the IDs in the cart.

###### Issues with add to cart in URL

If you don't redirect to the cart page after the product has been added, when the checkout refreshes the `?add-to-cart=ID` query parameter will remain in the URL. This means that if you refresh the checkout page, the product will be added again. To solve this, either tick "Redirect to the basket page after successful addition" in Woocommerce Settings > Products > General or change the add-t-cart url to something like `yourdomain.com/cart/?add-to-cart=ID`

Try:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'charity_checkout_add_on', 20 ); 
function charity_checkout_add_on() {
    $product_ids      = array( 59356, 59357, 59358 );
    $products_in_cart = array();
    $button_data      = array();

    // Gather product cart items in array
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $cart_product       = $cart_item['data'];
        $products_in_cart[] = $cart_product->get_id();
    }

    // Dynamically generate buttons
    $button_html = '';
    $last_button = end( $product_ids );
    foreach( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
        if( $product = wc_get_product( $product_id ) ) {
            $in_cart = ( in_array( $product->get_id(), $products_in_cart ) ) ? true : false;
            
            $button_classes = 'charity-button';
            if( $in_cart ) {
                $button_classes.= ' disabled';
            }
            if( $product_id === $last_button ) {
                $button_classes.= ' last';
            }

            $button_html .= sprintf(
                '<a class="%s"%s>%s</a>',
                esc_attr( $button_classes ),
                ( $in_cart ) ? '' : esc_url( 'href="?add-to-cart=' . $product->get_id() . '"' ),
                esc_html( get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . $product->get_price() )
            );
        };
    }
    ?>
    <h4>Make a Donation?</h4>
    <div id="charity-donation">
        <h6>Heading text</h6>
        <p>Explanation</p>
        <?php echo $button_html; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Your css class then could be something like:

```css
.charity-button.disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```